# Can unregistered cubit in blockprovider rebuild widget?

Tags: flutter, state, bloc, cubit

I have some cubit in one page like this

```
providers: [
      BlocProvider<HomeCubit>(
        create: ///,
      ),
      BlocProvider<SurveyListCubit>(
          create: ///),
      BlocProvider<LocationCubit>(
          create: ///)
    ],
```

SurveyListCubit and LocationCubit have their own state and different from HomeCubit state. Then I register the provider with HomeCubit and HomeState

```
child: BlocBuilder<HomeCubit, HomeState>
```

Will the listener only listen to HomeState changes or can also listen to SurveyListState and LocationState? I need to rebuild the widget when there's changes from either SurveyListState or LocationState